# why isn't merge sort O(N^2)? please look at this example

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

A bubble sort of 16 elements takes 15 steps of 2-2 comparison to sort them one by one.

A merge sort firstly divide them into 16 elements, and merge 2 each time, but the overall steps is still 15 if you draw the picture, i.e. 8+4+2+1=15
in such case, merge cost O(n) while 2-2 comparison cost O(n) so should be O(n^2).
why is it false?

Comment: 15 is less than 256 (n^2), isn't it? (while here comparison count is about 32)

Comment: MBo, isnt comparison count 15 which is the same as a bubble sort?

Comment: @MBo comparison count actually has a lower-bound of 32

Comment: Where the heck did you get the 15 number for either algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Merge sort has a time complexity of O(*n* log *n*).

It's easier to confirm this by closely inspecting the iterative implementation you've described. The algorithm scans the list log(*n*) times. In your example, it merges every pair, then every four, then every eight, then all sixteen, bringing it to a total of 4 = log<sub>2</sub>(16) iterations. Since the list itself is length *n*, the total time complexity is in the order of *n* log(*n*), which is validated by calculating that 64 elements in total are iterated by scanning a list of 16 items 4 times.

The fault in your analysis is incorrectly assuming that every merge is performed with a time complexity of O(*n*). The time complexity of each merge in a merge sort cannot trivially be represented in terms of *n*.

Answer (score 0):

I always found that the best way to visualise merge sort is to draw its recursion tree.

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume we are working with a list which size is a power of two.

#### Recursion depth

The first question we should ask is: what is the recursion depth which is attained?

Since on every recursion, merge sort divided the list into two, then the number of recursion until we reach the base case is equal to the number of time n can be divided by 2. That is *log(n)* by definition.

#### Steps at a given depth

We then count how many steps are taken to merge all sublists at a given recursion depth.

Suppose we are at depth *k*, where *k = 1* is the top level, we have 2<sup>k-1</sup> pairs of sublists of size *n / 2<sup>k</sup>* each. By merging the sublists two by two, we thus need *2<sup>k-1</sup> 
* (2 * n / 2<sup>k</sup>)* which is exactly *n* steps.

Your error comes from the above step, you wrongly assumed that a merge always takes *n* steps while it actually takes *n / 2<sup>k-1</sup>* where *k* is the recursion depth.

#### Conclusion

If we have *log(n)* recursion levels and each takes *n* steps, it follows that we have *n log(n)* steps to our algorithm.

Conclusion: Merge sort is *O(n log(n))*

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the logic error in my statement. The 2-2 comparison steps doesn't determine complexity alone, when you sort 1 element and 1 element, it cost only O(1) to do it, and 16 of such behavior becomes o(N), in that sense, a merge sort has logN times of merging, each merging takes some steps of 22 comparison but overall complexity of each time is still O(N).
And the power of merge sort is in the extra space it allocates, when new vector is created for smaller number of elements to be compared, it drops the comparison cost for each smaller subsets.

Comment: If you have anything to add to your question, just leave a comment or edit your question.